# How to insert two values into a list Pandas.Dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, dataframe

I have this problem, I would like to insert two values at the beginning and at the end of a list.

I have this initial dataframe:

```
source_x     destination_x   Path_Def
10.0.11.100  10.0.12.100     ['10.0.11.10', '10.0.1.2']
10.0.11.100  10.0.13.100     ['10.0.11.10', '10.0.1.6', '10.0.1.18']
10.0.11.100  10.0.14.100     ['10.0.11.10', '10.0.1.6', '10.0.1.18', '10.0.1.26']
10.0.11.100  10.0.22.100     ['10.0.11.10', '10.0.1.6', '10.0.1.14', '10.0.4.6', '10.0.2.5']
10.0.11.100  10.0.23.100     ['10.0.11.10', '10.0.1.6', '10.0.1.14', '10.0.6.6', '10.0.2.9']
10.0.11.100  10.0.24.100     ['10.0.11.10', '10.0.1.6', '10.0.1.14', '10.0.4.6', '10.0.2.18']
10.0.11.100  10.0.25.100     ['10.0.11.10', '10.0.1.6', '10.0.1.14', '10.0.6.6', '10.0.2.23']
```

The result I would like to obtain is this:

```
source_x     destination_x   Path_Def
10.0.11.100  10.0.12.100     ['10.0.11.100','10.0.11.10', '10.0.1.2', '10.0.12.100']
10.0.11.100  10.0.13.100     ['10.0.11.100','10.0.11.10', '10.0.1.6', '10.0.1.18','10.0.13.100']
10.0.11.100  10.0.14.100     ['10.0.11.100','10.0.11.10', '10.0.1.6', '10.0.1.18', '10.0.1.26','10.0.14.100']
10.0.11.100  10.0.22.100     ['10.0.11.100','10.0.11.10', '10.0.1.6', '10.0.1.14', '10.0.4.6', '10.0.2.5','10.0.22.100']
10.0.11.100  10.0.23.100     ['10.0.11.100','10.0.11.10', '10.0.1.6', '10.0.1.14', '10.0.6.6', '10.0.2.9','10.0.23.100']
....
```

This is my Code/Dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'source_x':[ '10.0.11.100', '10.0.11.100', '10.0.11.100', 
                               '10.0.11.100', '10.0.11.100', '10.0.11.100', '10.0.11.100'], 
                'destination_x':['10.0.12.100', '10.0.13.100', '10.0.14.100', 
                                '10.0.22.100', '10.0.23.100', '10.0.24.100', '10.0.25.100'], 
                'Path_Def':[['10.0.11.10', '10.0.1.2'],
           ['10.0.11.10', '10.0.1.6', '10.0.1.18'],
           ['10.0.11.10', '10.0.1.6', '10.0.1.18', '10.0.1.26'],
           ['10.0.11.10', '10.0.1.6', '10.0.1.14', '10.0.4.6', '10.0.2.5'],          
           ['10.0.11.10', '10.0.1.6', '10.0.1.14', '10.0.6.6', '10.0.2.9'],
           ['10.0.11.10', '10.0.1.6', '10.0.1.14', '10.0.4.6', '10.0.2.18'],
           ['10.0.11.10', '10.0.1.6', '10.0.1.14', '10.0.6.6', '10.0.2.23']]
})
```

How could this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can `apply`:

```
df['Path_Def'] = df.apply(lambda x: [x['source_x']] + x['Path_Def'] + [x['destination_x']], 
                          axis=1)
```

Output:

```
    source_x     destination_x    Path_Def
--  -----------  ---------------  ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 0  10.0.11.100  10.0.12.100      ['10.0.11.100', '10.0.11.10', '10.0.1.2', '10.0.12.100']
 1  10.0.11.100  10.0.13.100      ['10.0.11.100', '10.0.11.10', '10.0.1.6', '10.0.1.18', '10.0.13.100']
 2  10.0.11.100  10.0.14.100      ['10.0.11.100', '10.0.11.10', '10.0.1.6', '10.0.1.18', '10.0.1.26', '10.0.14.100']
 3  10.0.11.100  10.0.22.100      ['10.0.11.100', '10.0.11.10', '10.0.1.6', '10.0.1.14', '10.0.4.6', '10.0.2.5', '10.0.22.100']
 4  10.0.11.100  10.0.23.100      ['10.0.11.100', '10.0.11.10', '10.0.1.6', '10.0.1.14', '10.0.6.6', '10.0.2.9', '10.0.23.100']
 5  10.0.11.100  10.0.24.100      ['10.0.11.100', '10.0.11.10', '10.0.1.6', '10.0.1.14', '10.0.4.6', '10.0.2.18', '10.0.24.100']
 6  10.0.11.100  10.0.25.100      ['10.0.11.100', '10.0.11.10', '10.0.1.6', '10.0.1.14', '10.0.6.6', '10.0.2.23', '10.0.25.100']
```